# add a new column after fulfilling all conditions in python

Tags: python

I have a table like the following:

| AGE | CARD | SCORE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 1 | 20000 |
| 18 | 1 | 3000 |
| 25 | 0 | 2000 |

I want to add the "Status" column fulfilling all of the conditions; AGE>17, CARD = 1, and SCORE>2200.

| AGE | CARD | SCORE | STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 1 | 20000 | 0 |
| 18 | 1 | 3000 | 1 |
| 25 | 0 | 2000 | 0 |

Comment: Basically, I wanted to predict Status. I am using Logistic Regression and I am not able to get the prediction with the below functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the Boolean masking combining all the conditions, and convert the masking to integer type, then assign it back as a new column:

```py
df['STATUS'] = (
                (df['AGE'].gt(17))
                &(df['CARD'].eq(1))
                &(df['SCORE'].gt(2200))
            ).astype(int)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
   AGE  CARD  SCORE  STATUS
0   10     1  20000       0
1   18     1   3000       1
2   25     0   2000       0
```

Answer (score 1):

'*' is used for intersection in pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'AGE':[10,18,25],
                   'CARD': [1,1,0], 
                   'SCORE': [20000, 3000, 2000]})

df["STATUS"] = ((df['AGE'] >17) * (df['CARD'] == 1) * (df['SCORE'] >2200)).astype('int')
df.head()
```

Output:

```
AGE CARD    SCORE   STATUS
0   10  1   20000   0
1   18  1   3000    1
2   25  0   2000    0
```

Comment: For the next time, it would be better to edit the other answer instead of posting two answers (especially when one is deleted). Good answer with `*` BTW.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I thought Deleted Post is not visible to anyone except me

Comment: Normally, when you think the initial answer needs a major change, I would suggest you can delete, edit, then _undelete_ ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
df['Status'] = df.apply(lambda x: 1 if ((x['AGE']>17) and (x['CARD']==1) and (x['SCORE']>2200)) else 0 ,axis=1)
```